# How do I add two lines from two files to a single command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm still learning bash on my free time and what I'm trying to do is format a file that lists data of which two lines at a time are directly related and insert this data into a single command...for example: My list file -

```
line 1 data
line 2 data related to line 1
line 3 data
line 4 data related to line 3
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to find a way to add both related lines to a single command, and continue to add the next two lines to the said command etc. until the list is done.  The data would be inserted as options to the command...

```
COMMAND --OPTION1=line1data --OPTION2=line2data
```

The list should not be repeated and no line of data should be repeated.  So far what I've done is use grep to format the file into two separate files, the first file listing only the first line of data (without the following 2nd line of related data) i.e. line1 line3 line5 etc., and the second file consists of a list of the second line of related data i.e. line2 line4 etc...Now I'm probably making this waaaay to hard for myself but I was trying to put the data from both files into the command using something like the for command to loop the process...but I don't know how to take the first line of each formatted file (then take the next line of each file) and insert it into one command...

So here I am.  Also, is there anyway to make this easier and just take data two lines at a time from a file and input that into a command?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method would be this:

```
while read opt1; do
  read opt2
  COMMAND --OPTION1="$opt1" --OPTION2="$opt2"
done < input.txt
```

You can probably see the logic here -- we have a loop that reads a line into the variable `opt1`, where the first command in the loop consumes the next line into the variable `opt2`, and then uses the two variables to construct your command line. Done this way, it's a simple one-liner in bash (or POSIX shell -- there's nothing here which is exclusive to bash).

Another way to approach this is to use the `paste` command, which is not strictly part of bash, but comes with your OS. Note the following:

```
$ printf '1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n' | paste - -
1   2
3   4
5   6
```

This doesn't separate things for use the way you expressed in your question though, so a more complex loop would be in order. `paste` by default uses a <kbd>tab</kbd> as a separator. Assuming your input data doesn't include tab characters, you could use a construct like this:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read opt1 opt2; do
  COMMAND --OPTION1="$opt1" --OPTION2="$opt2"
done < <(paste - - < input.txt)
```

The logic here is that the `paste` command will construct single lines of input for our `read` commands, which gets its IFS set to the same separator that `paste` uses. The `<( ... )` construct is called "[Process Substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst)" in bash (you can find it in the man page), and is helpful if you want your `while` loop to populate variables that will be used later in the shell script .. but you could avoid the bashism here by using a pipe:

```
paste - - < input.txt | while IFS=$'\t' read opt1 opt2; do
  COMMAND --OPTION1="$opt1" --OPTION2="$opt2"
done
```

Note that the construct `$'\t'` (often called "format substitution" but described in the "[QUOTING](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)" section of the bash man page) to generate the tab also may not be universal, but does exist in many other shells besides bash, so it's still fairly portable.

While it's a little longer and involves an extra command, I consider the second method to be the most clear and readable. You should use whatever approach makes the most sense to YOU, so that you can maintain it more easily in the future.

Consider whether it would be beneficial or problematic to use the `-r` option for read, to handle backslashes and line continuation. I don't know your use case, so I can't make a recommendation on this other than that you be aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your file `input.txt` has following content

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

Use `awk` command to access the individual lines as follows:

`awk '{if(NR%2 == 0) {print "COMMAND --OPTION1="data1" --OPTION2="$0;}else{data1=$0;}}' input.txt`

In the above `awk` command , `NR` is variable which holds the current line number. `$0` is the complete line.

`NR%2` means checking whether the line number given by `NR` is divisible by `2` using the mod `%` operator.

- if `NR%2 equals 0` then the lines given by `NR` are all even numbered i.e 2, 4, 6, 8...
- if `NR%2 not equals 0` then the lines given by `NR` are all odd numbered i.e 1, 3, 5, 7...

  ```
  Output:    
  COMMAND --OPTION1=1 --OPTION2=2
  COMMAND --OPTION1=3 --OPTION2=4
  COMMAND --OPTION1=5 --OPTION2=6
  COMMAND --OPTION1=7 --OPTION2=8
  ```

Comment: Yup, that worked like a charm!  Now...could you give me an explanation about the % sign? Also, I was under the assumption that the brackets when used in bash {} only can contain numerical fields sich as {1..5} etc...thanks for the answer!

Comment: @NathanielDavidson, this answer provides you with a solution in `awk`, not in `bash`. The curly braces function differently in different languages. You might want to `man awk` to learn a bit about how this language works.

Comment: How do you deal with spaces or glob characters or quotes in the options? (answer: you can't without increasing insanely the complexity of your script). Bottom line: this is not a good method, it serializes data into code, instead of treating data as data.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: "it serializes data into code, instead of treating data as data".  something to make a note of. thanks :-)  But again, data would be read and needs to be formatted. So when we say "formatted" the code does get involved in the process.

Comment: Look how @ghoti treats _data_ in his answer: as _data!_ it will cope with any funny character: quotes, globs, spaces, parentheses and brackets, backslashes, semicolons and dollars. Yours will break with any of these.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: I do understand the concerns, but i tried putting random characters and all the special characters in the input file. To my surprise my and ghoti's solution showed same behavior. How can i provide you my input.txt for testing at your end?

Comment: The problem is that, eventually, the command `COMMAND` needs to be _executed_ with the given options. How are you going to execute your command? answer: you'll use some sort of `eval`, and this is where things will break.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: 'Eventually' part made the things clear :)

Comment: Please excuse my forum etiquette and the (lack of) details provided in my question...I work on cars for a living but computer languages have always intrigued me - so I'm kind of a closet-nerd...anyway gniourf is right...I these commands will be executed within my script and consecutively, not concurrently.

Comment: So even though this answer provides me with my desired output, and thus answers my question, it still didn't help me in terms of executing the commands in my bash script - which I should have mentioned in my original question...

Comment: The problem is when trying to make the 'for' loop read the output of awk, it reads the file as one command, not a list of commands...something about \n terminating each line?

Comment: @NathanielDavidson - thanks for the clarifications; aside from the lack of an attempt to solve this yourself, I didn't see a problem with what you presented in your question. For reference, if you *do* for some reason write code which writes (shell) code, one option can be to pipe the output through `sh` or `bash`.  Try `echo date | bash`. If this awk script *could* safely process your data and generate command lines, you could simply pipe it through the shell to execute commands. But in this case (or for any complex case) .. don't do that. :-)